# Need help to analysis & overcome an issue with LM358 OP-AMP

Tags: operational-amplifier, resistance

I want to measure the resistance of a coil which its resistance vary in accordance with its temperature coefficient of resistance, the resistance range of the coil vary between 0.12 Ω to 5.00 Ω, at end to calculate its temperature.

The amplified output from the LM358 will be used by an ADC of a microcontroller to determine the resistance of coil (10-bits).

All system (microcontroller + OP-Amp single supply) will be run on 3.0 volts, and that's restricted as this system is a portable-battery device.

**Problem** 
I have bad luck with the accuracy as the following :
 - Above 0.35 Ω the accuracy is somehow acceptable (of course looking for more accuracy).
 - Below 0.35 Ω the accuracy going negatively in the side that effect the purpose of the system as mentioned in the text on the picture.

The problem is that the 0.01 Ω error in measuring the coil's resistance at 0.12Ω (actual resistance of the coil) means an error of 11.2 degrees Celsius which is not acceptable.

at 5.0 Ω the 0.01 Ω error means only 0.33 degrees Celsius which is acceptable.

The method of measuring the resistance depends on a constant current of 0.299 Amp.

At 5.0 Ω the output from the OP-Amp is 1.495 volts, so I used the below equation to estimate the resistance of the coil.

```
Coil R = [Vout x 5 Ω] / 1.495
```

On the picture I mentioned the accuracy problem in numbers as observed.

Note: observation done on Multisim 14.1, not an actual circuit.

So what I missing here ?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you are measuring a 0.1 ohm resistance then, reversing your formula, you expect to measure an output voltage of 29.9 mV. The first "notable" thing is that you are getting quite close to the lower permissable limit for the LM358 (20 mV above ground).

However, you should also note the input offset voltage for the LM358 - the data sheet states it as having a maximum value up to 7 mV. There will also be resistor tolerance effects these will add more error.

Try altering the model file for the LM358 to see if there is an input offset voltage value you could tweak to better understand the problem. Also try increasing the supply voltage - the LM358 is "said" to operate down to 3 volts but there is little information in the data sheet that tells you how it might perform.

Comment: Thanks for reply, the supply voltage is restricted due to I will use a Li-Ion battery that will get lower to 3.0 volts (battery die limit) as a minimum permissible voltage out of it, the tiny size of device & the no need for another battery (no need for more current or voltage higher than 20 amp & 4.2 volts) restricts me to operate the Op-Amp at 3.0 volts so that near battery-die stage the system can still measure resistance.

I was reading the datasheet carefully & yeah, no more info or graphs for that voltage supply.. I will go with your advice and will check the parameters of the OP-AMP

Comment: Simplest thing to do is raise the supply voltage in the sim to see if better accuracy is obtained. I'm not saying that is a fix. I'm saying it allows you to see if things improve. I wouldn't use an LM358 at 3 volts based on the data sheet no matter what sim results I might get.

Comment: I got your point, also I'm going to breadboard a real circuit to get a full understanding.. thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Your lM358 is configured for a gain of 1 .Andy is correct about the chips bad behavour when the inputs are close to ground .The LM358 is a bad beetle . You could reduce all your resister values by a factor of 10 .This could be helpful if you have already done a PCB and do not want change .You could use a better opamp ,there are better devices that are pin compatable .You could run a split supply where the LM 358 will perform much better .Better still you could remove the opamp and run straight into the ADC .